Running Python Azure function locally. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: WorkerConfig for runtime: python not found
Attempting to run a python azure function locally but getting a
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: WorkerConfig for runtime: python not found."
This is despite having a venv with python installed and it being installed on local machine. VS Code is being run as admin as well.
Output from terminal when trying to run
Full error here:
[2024-09-05T15:23:14.773Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'dac4260d-fa20-49b8-a225-97dc6b2aceab'.
[2024-09-05T15:23:14.777Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: WorkerConfig for runtime: python not found.
[2024-09-05T15:23:14.790Z] Failed to stop host instance '4975e599-c38c-4003-a5ab-30f8005eef48'.
[2024-09-05T15:23:14.793Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: The host has not yet started.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Have attempted to run the function and see an output with the endpoint and local host. Instead getting above errors

Please post the an error as text, not a screenshot.

I'm having the exact same problem

Are you using the .msi installer from the azure function core tool github? It worked when I used that. (instead of downloading the ZIP file and then adding the directory to Path.)

Hello, this may be the reason why Azure Functions can't find an interpreter or configuration. How did you download the Azure Function core tools? You can try to modify "azureFunctions.pythonVenv":".venv", "azureFunctions.pythonInterpreter":"/path/to/python" in the settings.json file to set the path information of the interpreter.

Added full error

@TheSingingSDK, please provide your host.json and local.settings.json.

Also try installing Azure function core tools using npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4.

You're missing the python worker - check the workers directory in your install of core tools, if it's empty, that's the problem.


Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: WorkerConfig for runtime: python not found.

To resolve this error, install Azure function core tools using the command:
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4


Delete the existing .venv folder and create a new virtual environment.
Validate the Python path and versions in the .venv/pyvenv.cfg.
pyvenv.cfg:
home = C:\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.11.9
executable = C:\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
command = C:\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m venv c:\Users\v-pkothaveer\pyfn1\.venv

Make sure you have below settings in .vscode=>Settings.json as @Tr33hugger mentioned:
{
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguageModel": 2
}

Make sure you have configured host.json and local.settings.json as below:
host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}


If you are facing issue with azure-functions-core-tools, Please follow the steps below which personally helped me to resolve my issue.
Step 1: Uninstall via NPM
Run the command in Powershell and uninstall Azure Func Core Tools globally:

npm uninstall -g azure-functions-core-tools@4

If you are unsure of the version then you can use the command below instead:

npm uninstall -g azure-functions-core-tools

Step 2: Restart Your System
After uninstalling, restarting is I recommend.
Step 3: Reinstall via NPM
Run the command in Powershell

npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4

Alternative: Using Chocolatey
If youa are facing any issue with npm then please use Chocolatey (a package manager for Windows).

Open PowerShell as an Administrator and run:


choco uninstall azure-functions-core-tools


Once uninstalled, you can reinstall it using:


choco install azure-functions-core-tools --version=4

Verification
After reinstalling, cross check that the Azure functions core tools are installed properly:

func --version

Start Your Azure Function
After reinstalling, go to your project dir and delete the existing virtualenv and recreate one and then run:

func start

This will successfully start your Azure Function.
Note
The preffered way is using npm.
